# Followed git-flow model, not sure if branches are correct

Tags: git, git-flow

I tried to follow the [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model) branching model in my Github repo.

After following the instructions, I [arrived at the point](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#finishing-a-release-branch) of merging the `release` branch into the `develop` branch. I did that with no issues, and proceeded to remove the `release` branch (also with no issues).

Now I'm positioned in the `develop` branch, and when I do a `git status` it tells me there are commits that need to be pushed:

```
$ Your branch is ahead of «origin/develop« by 3 commits.
```

These are the three commits I did on the, now merged and deleted, `release` branch.

At this point I'm not sure I should be getting that notice, but I `git push` anyway as `git` is asking me to.

Finally I got to Github and look at my network, which looks like this:

[image]

Is this how it these two branches are supposed to look after following the git-flow model? The green line confuses me, as I would've expected to see only two lines: `master` and `develop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expected:

- The **black** line to be as it is
- The **green** line to come from the far left

The unexpected:

- I suppose you branched `develop` from the `release` branch

In this case everything will be fine if you branch the future `release` branches from the `develop` branch.

The two **blue** dots you see after the branching of the **green** line are equivalent to the **green** dots in the first picture of the [git flow article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

---

If you did branch the `release` from the `develop` then the picture is really confusing because it looks like you merged the `develop` into the `release`.

Comment: Yeah, I probably made a mess. That's not the end of it though, I continued working and now it looks like this http://pasteboard.co/11tJQ6RIj.png :P
Thank you!

Comment: Regarding your new picture: It looks like you merged your `feature-branch` back into `develop`: correct. But afterwards merged (more of a fast-forward) merged `develop` into `feature-branch` too. Following the git-flow you should not do that :P